how to provision routes in apisix traditional mode so that they are automatically loaded on service startup
I want to provision routes in APISIX traditional mode.
I want when I up the apisix service using Docker/docker-compose some default routes are automatically loaded in apisix.
I am using the docker-compose on apache's apisix github
I understand that the config.yaml file is loaded in traditional mode (defining roles) and apisix.yaml file is loaded in standalone mode (defining routes and upstreams)
If I am using etcd as config manager how can I set the routes that are automatically loaded in etcd.
